# Issues in property binding a value to a custom directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have a question.component.html template where some options of a particular question are rendered. When a user clicks on any one of the options, if that's correct, I am trying to change the background color of that particular option to yellow, otherwise if he clicks on wrong answer the color should be red.

Here are my codes -

**question.component.html**

```
`<div class="options">
    <ol *ngFor="let option of optionsList; let i = index">
        <li (click)="optionChose(i)">
            <div appChangeBg 
                [isCorrect] = "isCorrectOptionChosen" 
                 class="card">
                 {{ option }}
            </div>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>`
```

**question.component.ts**

```
`export class QuestionComponent implements OnInit {
   isCorrectOptionChosen: boolean;
     optionChose(index: number) {
        if (index === this.correctOptionIndex) {
            this.isCorrectOptionChosen = true;
        } else {
           this.isCorrectOptionChosen = false;
        }
     }
 }`
```

**change-bg.directive.ts**

```
`@Directive({
    selector: '[appChangeBg]'
 })
 export class ChangeBgDirective {
    @Input() isCorrect: boolean = false;

    constructor(private elRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}

    @HostListener('click') answer() {
      if (this.isCorrect === true) {
         this.renderer.setStyle(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'background-color', 'yellow');
    }else{
       this.renderer.setStyle(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'background-color', 'red');
    }
  }
}
```

But the value of **isCorrect** variable in the directive is coming as undefined for the first time, and hence even if the user clicks on the correct option, red color is being displayed which is not the color I want. Why is this happening even if I property bind the correct value in my template. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here and how I need to solve this issue.`

Answer (score 0):

Think that is due to the click event to call `optionChose` method and assign value to `isCorrectOptionChosen` variable doesn't guarantee to be executed first before the "click" event is fired for `ChangeBgDirective`.

Instead of assigning the value from `optionChose` method only when it is clicked, this can be fixed by providing the value to `correctOption` directly when the HTML template is rendered.

Note that, calling the method from the HTML template may lead to performance issues (you can find a lot of blogs discussing it, for example [Avoid calling expressions in template of Angular](https://blog.devgenius.io/avoid-calling-expressions-in-template-of-angular-39439c547653)). You may need to implement a Pipe as below:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'correctOption',
})
export class CorrectOptionPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    let correctOptionIndex = args;

    return value === correctOptionIndex;
  }
}
```

Don't forget to register the `CorrectOptionPipe` in the AppModule.

Next, remove `(click)="optionChose(i)"` from HTML, and apply the `CorrectOptionPipe`.

```
<ol *ngFor="let option of optionsList; let i = index">
    <li>
        <div appChangeBg 
            [isCorrect]="i | correctOption: correctOptionIndex" 
             class="card">
             {{ option }}
        </div>
    </li>
</ol>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dt7htf?file=src%2Fapp.component.ts)